# jquery menu, different control of menu in different stages of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, menu

Hi guys could you help me with my menu. I want that all buttons in a second stage could be opened only one at the tyme. Lets say I press **stage 2 a** button, then I press **stage 2 b** button and **stage 2 a** button would closse itself but leaving **stage 1** intact. And I want to make it work with many stage 2 buttons not only two (**stage 2 a** and **stage 2 b**) which I have now. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
function prepareList() {
    $('#game_menu_mail').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })

    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t1ko1tny/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if the element clicked is a second stage element or not. If it is, then hide all second stage items before showing the one being clicked:

```
function prepareList() {
    var $gameMenuMail = $('#game_menu_mail'),
        secondStage = '#game_menu_mail > li > ul';
    $('#game_menu_mail').find('li:has(ul)').click(function (event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.is(secondStage + ' > li')) {
                $this.closest(secondStage).find('li')
                    .removeClass('expanded')
                    .children('ul').hide('medium');
            }
            $this.toggleClass('expanded').children('ul').toggle('medium');

        }
        return false;
    })
        .addClass('collapsed')
        .children('ul').hide();
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t1ko1tny/7/)